# Is there a wordpress pluggin that displays a page in a lightbox style window?

Tags: lightbox, wordpress, popupwindow

Is there a wordpress pluggin that displays a page in a lightbox style window?

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use [modalbox][1] or [fancybox](http://blog.moskis.net/downloads/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) plugin